# Stream camera video from iOS device to another iOS device

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

Is there any open-source library or code or which handles the streaming of the camera video of one iOS device to another? Or are there at least some best-practice?

I found some questions here, but they all deal with audio-only streaming.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [this](https://github.com/nicnocquee/iPad-iPhone-Photo-Booth--iPhone-as-Wireless-Cam-for-iPad-) project in github.